# Google Play Service library missing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am new to Google Maps on Android. In my sample Map application I add **Google Play Service** library, press **Apply** button and then press **OK** button.

Then again library which was added see with red mark each time.

[image: Screen shot of project properties]

I have also update play service .

Comment: Copy that project library to your workspace also with same path of your current project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the both your project and lib project should be in same work space. So Your need to copy that library project in to your project work space  then add it.

(OR)

Eclipse -> import -> existing android code -> browse -> navigate to google-play-services_lib FOLDER and import that.

then, on your project, control click -> properties -> android -> libraries, add -> select the project you just imported -> ok

Hope it helps..

Comment: See my updated answer now..If still you didn't get let me know

Comment: Yes same thing i did also

Comment: check your project and that lib are in same work space?

Comment: or just updated Google Play services under the Extras folder in Android SDK Manager

Comment: When i copy google-play-services_lib to my workspace then import it but gives error that invalid project discription. Reason Invalide project discription

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45522/discussion-between-shylendra-and-kiran-zabuzalabs)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the google-play-services-lib as a library-project. They updated the sdk. There are several tutorials around. For Eclipse it is easy:

> Right click project -> properties -> Android

[image]

For more detailed walkthroughs:

[Import library-project](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse -> import -> existing android code -> browse -> navigate to google-play-services_lib FOLDER (android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject).

then, on your project, control click -> properties -> android -> libraries, add -> select the project you just imported -> ok